# FTPClient no modo passivo

Tags: java, jsp, ftp

Estou com problema ao tentar conectar o FTP. 
Pelo FileZila, ele funciona normalmente.... mas quando tento por esse trecho de codigo, ele gera a seguitne exceção: j**ava.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind**
O erro ocorre quando eu chamo o ftp.connect(); Pesquisando a solução, vi que eu tinha que usar o FTP no modo passivo, mas nao consegui, ja tentei usar: enterRemoteActiveMode(), enterLocalPassiveMode(), enterLocalActiveMode() mas nada resolveu..... alguém tem alguma ideia ?

```
try {
        this.beginTransaction(xxxxxxx);     

        //Configura Conexão FTP
        InetAddress localhost = xxxxx;
        InetAddress destino =xxxx; 
        cdPortaFTP = xxxxx;
        if(!ftp.isConnected()){             
            //Faz conexão FTP               
            ftp.connect(destino, cdPortaFTP, localhost, cdPortaFTP);
        }
        //ftp.enterRemoteActiveMode();
        //ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        //ftp.enterLocalActiveMode();

        // verifica se conectou com sucesso e faz login
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode())) {
            ftp.login(xxxx,xxxx);                       
        } else {
            ftp.disconnect();
            throw new Exception();
        }
        .....
        .....
        .....
```

Comment: Esse erro geralmente ocorre quando a porta que você está acessando já esta em uso? Tem certeza que não existe nada rodando nela. PS poste a stacktrace de erro

Comment: - Stack Trace: 
 java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind 
 
-at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) 
 
-at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:402) 
 
-at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:576)
 
-at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:241) 
 
-at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:226)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Eu estava usando o **FTP no modo ativo**:

```
if(!ftp.isConnected()){                             
    ftp.connect(destino, cdPortaFTP, localhost, cdPortaFTP);
}
    ftp.enterLocalActiveMode();
```

Quando na verdade, precisava usar o **FTP no modo passivo** pois acessam a internet via firewall/nat. E o passivo também não precisa do bind local. Então coloquei no modo passivo:

```
if(!ftp.isConnected()){             
    //Faz conexão FTP               
    ftp.connect(destino, cdPortaFTP);
}           
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

Comment: Obs.: Portas abaixo de mil e pouco, são restrita a administradores. Então, utilize portas mais altas.